# Restoring database to a point in time not working

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, backup-restoration

I have a database that is backed up nightly via a maintenance plan I created using the wizard in management studio.  The recovery model is set to full.

On the 26th something happened and SQL Agent was shut down (or maybe the computer was reset and it didn't start back up properly).  I didn't realize it until about 5 days ago at which time I turned it back on (and am now in the process of making sure I get notified when SQL Agent is off in the future).

I need to restore the database to a few points in time between the 26th and now, but when I try to do this Management Studio acts like it is doing it but ends up just restoring to the 26th no matter what time I actually specify (unless the time I specify is after the point when I turned Sql Agent back on).

Even though it didn't get backed up for a little over a week, I would expect the log to still have kept all the transactions so that I could restore to any point in time.  Shouldn't I still be able to restore to any point in time or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party tool to specify exactly what transactions you want to be rolled back while recovering to a specific point in time, using various filters and even be able to review them before the recovery process. Check out the **[Reverting your SQL Server database back to a specific point in time](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/reverting-your-sql-server-database-back-to-a-specific-point-in-time/)** online article for detailed information

Disclaimer: I work as a Product Support Engineer at ApexSQL